# Question about voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider

If you look at the diagram there is only a + after the R1 resistor.
Not a + after the R2 resistor. But I was wondering why is there an arrow to the right after the R2 resistor. If I connect a led as in the diagram (the red color), then that light does nothing. Only if I break the connection from after R2 to Vin then the 2nd led works.

Can someone explain what is going on?

In case it matters, I have 2 10K pot meters and a 9volt battery.

[image]

Comment: The arrow just means *"plug this wire where you want"*. It isn't meant to indicate the direction of current. The bottom LED indeed can't turn on, since you're connecting it between ground and ground.

Comment: There should be a `-` after the R2 resistor. The `+` and `-` are supposed to indicate the polarity of the output voltage of the divider, which is the voltage across R2.

Comment: It depends on the type of LED - part number please.

Answer (score 1):

In essence this is what your original circuit looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1VpVa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The arrows don't really mean anything, they are just a node from which voltage is measured.
And when you add the LEDs it looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGwIhp.png)</sup>
The bottom LED is not lighting up because there is no voltage across it.
D1 is lighting up because there is a voltage across it, but D2 is just shorted. The voltage on both sides of it is the same, so no current will flow through D2.

Usually, in a case like this, we also include a negative label, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzGIiJ.png)</sup>
Which means we are measuring (or solving for) the voltage across R2. Sometimes this is just left to:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ8fwk.png)</sup>

When you say you

> break the connection from after R2 to Vin

This is what I assume you mean:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMue7D.png)</sup>

In this case, there *is* a voltage across D2, so current will flow through it.  In this case, there will not be as much current flowing through D2 as there is through D1, because the current also has to flow through the potentiometer R2 to get to ground.

In this description, I am oversimplifying LEDs some, because if there isn't enough of a voltage across the LED in the forward direction (usually about 3v for LEDs), not enough current will flow for the LED to turn on. However, since you seem to be using potentiometers in this setup, you may be adjusting those for the LEDs to have enough of a forward bias to turn on.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the cathode of the voltage source is grounded.

First: Connecting LEDs to test voltages may be tricky, I would recommend using a multimeter instead. That is because LEDs are non-linear, and require a minimum voltage across them before they conduct any significant current (produce any light). This voltage is often referred to as the *forward voltage*.

The bottom LED cannot turn on in the schematic you drew, because the voltage across it is 0, which is definitely less than the forward voltage of any LED I have seen.

The top LED will turn on only if the divided voltage Vout, which your equation for is correct, is close to the forward voltage of the top LED.

Disconnecting R2 from the cathode of the voltage source (ground) results in a tricky situation. Three operating points for the circuit could be:
1.) The voltage source is less than the forward voltage of the LEDs and both LEDs are off.
2.) The voltage source is greater than the forward voltage of the LEDs to the point that when both LEDs are on,the LEDs are drawing current, and the LED voltages have been dropped across the resistors, there is enough voltage at both LEDs to keep them fully on.
3.) Somewhere in between where the LEDs are barely on.

I am guessing you are in an introductory circuits class. This will be very clear after a semiconductor class where you will be analyzing circuits with non-linear elements like diodes, FETs, and BJTs.

Answer (score 0):

In your original circuit the only Ground connections shown are on the LED cathodes, so no current can flow through the LEDs.  The black circuit is "floating" - it has no connection to ground.

The other answers have assumed that the negative side of the battery is connected to Ground, and therefore to the LED cathodes.  In this case, the top LED may light, if there is sufficient voltage between Ground and the R1/R2 junction.

With the negative side of the battery Grounded, both sides of the bottom LED are connected to Ground, so there can be no voltage across it, and it will not light.